# How to access 'expect' in jest setupFiles

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to create a [custom matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers) in Jest.  I would expect that this should go in my jest-setup.js file, specified in my jest.config.js file.

**jest-setup.js**

```js
// ...

expect.extend({
    myCustomMatcher(received, val) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, while `jest` is a global variable at this point in the execution, it appears that `expect` is not.  I can put my extension in a helper file and import that file for any test suite that uses it, but that seems like the wrong solution.

Is there a way to access `expect` from the `jest` variable (or some other means)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `setupFilesAfterEnv` to do that. From [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfilesafterenv-array) (emphasis mine):

> setupFilesAfterEnv [array]
>
> A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing framework before each test. Since setupFiles executes before the test framework is installed in the environment, *this script file presents you the opportunity of running some code immediately after the test framework has been installed in the environment.*